# How to make each authenticated user only see their own product

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to figure out how an authenticated user can only see products from their dashboard, i.e., every user has unique products list, and be able to create his own products. What i see now is if any user creates,delete or list product all users get affected.

I have tried to search other tutorials but didn't get the solution.

web.php

```
Route::group(['prefix'=>'seller', 'middleware'=>     ['auth']],function() {
Route::get('/',function (){
    return view('seller.index', compact('products'));
});
Route::resource('product', 'productController');
Route::get('/seller', 'ProductController@seller')->name('seller');
});
```

User.php

```
 public function products()
 {
  return $this->hasMany(Products_model::class);
 }
```

Products_model

```
class products_model extends Model
{
protected $table='products';
protected $primaryKey='id';
protected $fillable=   ['pro_name','pro_price','pro_info','image','stock','category_id'];
}
```

ProductController

```
class productController extends Controller
{

public function index()
{
   $products=products_model::all();
   return view('seller.product.index',compact('products'));
}

public function user()
{
return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}

public function create()
{

    return view('seller.product.create');

}

public function seller()
{
   $products=products_model::all();
   return view('seller.product.index',compact('products'));
}

public function store(Request $request)
{
    $formInput=$request->except('image');
    $this->validate($request, [
     'pro_name'=> 'required',
     'pro_price'=> 'required',
     'pro_info'=> 'required',
     'image'=>'image|mimes:png,jpg,jpeg|max:10000'
    ]);

    $image=$request->image;
    if($image){
        $imageName=$image->getClientOriginalName();
        $image->move('images', $imageName);
        $formInput['image']=$imageName;
    }

    products_model::create($formInput);
    return redirect()->back();
}

public function show($id)
{
    //
}

public function edit($id)
{
    //
}

public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    //
}

public function destroy($id)
{
   $deleteData=products_model::findOrFail($id);
   $deleteData->delete();

   return redirect()->back();
}
```

}

I want every user to have their unique dashboard, which means if a user deletes or creates a product it should only show in his dashboard without affecting others.

Answer (score 1):

Wherever you need to display only the authenticated user's products, change your query to filter out other peoples products:

```php
public function controllerAction(Request $request)
{  
    $userId = $request->user()->id;
    // or $userId = Auth::id(); (Via the Auth facade)
    // or $userId = auth()->id();

    $products = products_model::where('user_id', $userId)->get();
}
```

Comment: What should I change or remove and replace with that code? @Jack Robertson

Comment: `products_model::all();` should be `products_model::where('user_id', $userId)->get();` and `products_model::findOrFail($id);` should be `products_model::where('user_id', $userId)->findOrFail($id);`

Comment: Now it says "Undefined variable: userId" @Jack

Comment: Because you need to copy over the bit where I define `$userId` ;) Or just replace any reference of `$userId` with `auth()->id()`.

Comment: I changed the code but I get this error "Call to undefined method App\User::id()"@Jack

Comment: My fault, `id` is not a method but a property when called directly from the user object. See my updated answer.

Comment: Now am getting this error `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'user_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `products` where `user_id` = 1)`@Jack

Answer (score 0):

In your product model you need add the user_id to able relate the tables user with products:

```
class products_model extends Model
{
    protected $table='products';
    protected $primaryKey='id';
    protected $fillable=   ['user_id',   'pro_name','pro_price','pro_info','image','stock','category_id']; 
}
```

After in you controller you can filter the products by user and return these, at create new product can get the user logged id and put in new product

Comment: I added that in model and product table but i'm still getting an error `Call to undefined method App\User::id()` @bayocr

Comment: you should add it in the database as well and save it accordingly and fetch it

Comment: @msbomrel what do you mean save well? I added to the database as suggested but I'm still getting the error `Call to undefined method App\User::id()`

Comment: Where do I put 'User_id' in database? @bayocr

Comment: @joh yes in database, if you are using the orm to create database you only need add user_id into you product model, if you are creating database manually yo need add a foreing key of user   in your product table

Comment: @bayocr please look at this updated question [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56501018/array-map-argument-2-should-be-an-array?noredirect=1&lq=1]