# array_map(): Argument #2 should be an array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-5

I'm getting this error`array_map(): Argument #2 should be an array` when a user trying to create a product

I changed my code from this solutions [How to make each authenticated user only see their own product](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56496813/how-to-make-each-authenticated-user-only-see-their-own-product), and now it gives me that error.

ProductController

```
class productController extends Controller
{

public function index(Request $request)
{
    $userId = $request->user()->id;
    $products = products_model::where('user_id', $userId)->get();
   return view('seller.product.index',compact('products'));
}




public function create()
{  
    return view('seller.product.create');
}

public function seller()
{
   $products=products_model::all();
   return view('seller.product.index',compact('products'));
}


public function store(Request $request)
{

    $formInput=$request->except('image');
    $this->validate($request, [
     'pro_name'=> 'required',
     'pro_price'=> 'required',
     'pro_info'=> 'required',
     'user_id' => \Auth::id(),
     'image'=>'image|mimes:png,jpg,jpeg|max:10000'
    ]);

    $image=$request->image;
    if($image){
        $imageName=$image->getClientOriginalName();
        $image->move('images', $imageName);
        $formInput['image']=$imageName;
    }

    products_model::create($formInput);
    return redirect()->back();
}


public function show($id)
{
    //
}


public function edit($id)
{
    //
}


public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    //
}


public function destroy($id)
{
   $userId = $request->user()->id();
   $deleteData=products_model::where('user_id', $userId)->findOrFail($id);
   $deleteData->delete();

   return redirect()->back();
}
}
```

Products_model

```
class products_model extends Model
{
protected $table='products';
protected $primaryKey='id';
protected $fillable= ['user_id','pro_name','pro_price','pro_info','image','stock','category_ id'];
}
```

Products table

```
class CreateProductsTable extends Migration
{

public function up()
{
    Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('pro_name');
        $table->integer('pro_price');
        $table->text('pro_info');
        $table->integer('stock');
        $table->string('image')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->bigInteger('user_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
}


public function down()
{
    Schema::dropIfExists('products');
}
}
```

After updating my code now am getting this error`SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'user_id' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into`products`(`pro_name`,`pro_price`,`stock`,`pro_info`,`i`

Comment: What function is giving u this error?

Comment: @MateusJunges the store function. `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Validation/ValidationRuleParser.php`  and highlights this line `return array_map([$this, 'prepareRule'], $rule)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your validate function. Instead of use `$this->validate()`,
use `$request->validate()` method:

```php
$request->validate([
   'pro_name'=> 'required',
   'pro_price'=> 'required',
   'pro_info'=> 'required',
   'user_id' => 'required|integer',
   'image'=>'image|mimes:png,jpg,jpeg|max:10000'
]);
```

If the validation rules pass, your code will keep executing normally; however, if validation fails, an exception will be thrown and the proper error response will automatically be sent back to the user.

**Another solution:**

Add

```php
use Validator;
```

to your class.

```php
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'pro_name'=> 'required',
    'pro_price'=> 'required',
    'pro_info'=> 'required',
    'user_id' => 'required|integer',
    'image'=>'image|mimes:png,jpg,jpeg|max:10000'
]);

if($validator->fails()){
    //Validation does not pass logic here
}else{
    //
}
```

**One more:**
Create a [form request](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#creating-form-requests), with

> php artisan make:request RequestName

The file will be created in `app\Http\Requests` directory.

Within the file, add your rules to the `rules` method:

```php
public function rules()
{
    return [
       'pro_name'=> 'required',
       'pro_price'=> 'required',
       'pro_info'=> 'required',
       'user_id' => 'required|integer',
    ];
}
```

Change the `authorize` method, to return `true`:

```php
public function authorize()
{
    return true;
}
```

In your `store` method, swap the `Request $request` with `RequestName $request`.
Now you don't need to validate the `$request` inside `store` method. It will go to store only if the validation succeed;

Your `store` method now should looks like

```php
public function store(RequestName $request)
{
    $formInput=$request->except('image');

    $image=$request->image;
    if($image){
        $imageName=$image->getClientOriginalName();
        $image->move('images', $imageName);
        $formInput['image']=$imageName;
    }

    products_model::create(array_merge(
        $formInput, ['user_id' => Auth::user()->id]
    ));
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

> Dont forget to `use` App\Http\Requests\RequestName

If validation fails, a redirect response will be generated to send the user back to their previous location. The errors will also be flashed to the session so they are available for display. If the request was an AJAX request, a HTTP response with a 422 status code will be returned to the user including a JSON representation of the validation errors.
You can learn more about request validation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#quick-writing-the-validation-logic).

[EDIT]
I change the `users_id` rule to `user_id`, to match with your foreign key name.
I think you made a typo here when you asked the question.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194625/discussion-on-answer-by-mateus-junges-array-map-argument-2-should-be-an-arra).

Comment: @BhargavRao sorry about that